# Online Flash creator

Tags: flash, api

Is there any API or plugin for creating flash files online? My aim is to create an online editor in which the visitors can import their images, add texts and animation properties to it and save it as a swf file. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP you could give the [SWF functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/swf.examples-basic.php) a try.
There is also [FreeMovie](http://freemovie.sourceforge.net/) as well as [Ming](http://www.libming.org/).

Comment: I encountered some problems with MING. Now let me try FreeMovie. Thank you as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://wonderfl.net

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's close.

Comment: I am looking forward to create one similar to the link you given